# Why is the setPosition(xPos,yPos) wrapping at yPos=y*40 where y = 20 (yPos=800)?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm experimenting with making my own tile map. 
First, using Paint, I created several png images and then resized them to 40p by 40p images. (40_Brick01.png, 40_Brick02.png, 40_Water01.png, etc).

I then loaded them to their respective Texture variables.

I created a Sprite array of 48 by 27 to cover the 1920x1080 res screen in 40 pixal increments.
Using for loops and if/else statements I assigned each Sprite a texture based on the logic I used for the if else statements.
Inside these for loops I assigned positions to the Sprites using  `m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(xPos, yPos);` where `xPos = x*40; yPos = y*40;`

Then using embedded for loops I executed the draw command.

Most of the screen loads fine, but the last 6 lines/rows of tiles weren't populating.

I commented out the first block of tiles at the top of the screen and discovered the missing tiles were hiding "under the sea" of the just commented out tiles.

I selected two tiles (0,23) and (0,26) and discovered they were displaying in the locations for tiles (1,2) and (1,5).  This is where I discovered that everything with a y start location greater than 800 is moving over to the next x column and proceeding from y=0.

When I use `m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(0, 920);` and `m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(0, 1040);` instead of `m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(xPos, yPos);` then tiles (0,23) and (0,26) position correctly.

I have tried multiple different ways of variablizing the input to the setPosition function but they all have the same effect.  After plugging in some debugging checks, I find that the variables are being populated to their correct respective coordinates, but somehow it is getting corrupted in the setPosition call.

**Why is it wrapping when using the variables, but not when using values directly?**

An alternative way of doing what I'm attempting is here: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-vertex-array.php

But I'd like to figure out why my method doesn't work before borrowing another method.

**Edit:**
I've tried:

```
Vector2f m_TileGrid; //declared in .h

//in .cpp
m_TileGrid.x = 0.0;
m_TileGrid.y = 0.0;
for (int x = 0; x < 48; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 27; y++)
    {
        m_TileGrid.x = x * 40.f; //Tried with just 40 as well
        m_TileGrid.y = y * 40.f;
        m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(m_TileGrid);
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
//in .cpp
int xPos = 0;  //Tried with float and double
int yPos = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 48; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 27; y++)
    {
        xPos = x * 40.0; //Tried with just 40 as well and 40.f
        yPos = y * 40.0;
        m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(xPos,yPos);
    }
}
```

The only time I get anything to populate "below" y=800 IE where y>=840 is when I do stuff like the following:

```
if (y == 23 && x == 0)
{
    m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(0, 920);
}
if (y == 26 && x == 0)
{
    m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(0, 1040);
}
```

**Additional Info:**
I just discovered that it is setting the positions for this Sprites before the window size is defined.  This shouldn't matter as the draw command doesn't happen until after the window size is defined.  Unless it is doing some pre-processing on my variables and wrapping them before the window is defined.  As the positions do not change it cannot correct that in the while loop that refreshes the screen, redrawing everything.  Where as if I put a direct value in- a constant, mayhaps no pre-processing is occurring. **Doesn't seem to be the case as I have now tried setting the position after the window creation.**

I don't know if I can get the sample code any smaller and still demonstrate the effect:

```
//Tim.h
//Adopted and adapted from Bob.h from http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-a-simple-game-engine-in-c-plus-plus/
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

class Tim
{
private:
    Vector2f m_TileGrid;
    Texture m_Cobble01, m_Water05;

    Sprite m_TileSprite[48][21];


public:
    Tim();
    Sprite getTileSprite(int, int);
    void setTileSpritePos(int, int);

};

//Tim.cpp
//Adopted and adapted from Bob.ccp from http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-a-simple-game-engine-in-c-plus-plus/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tim.h"

Tim::Tim()
{

    m_Cobble01.loadFromFile("C:\\Visual Studio Stuff\\Projects\\Simple Game Engine\\Simple Game Engine\\40_Cobble01.png");
    m_Water05.loadFromFile("C:\\Visual Studio Stuff\\Projects\\Simple Game Engine\\Simple Game Engine\\40_Water05.png");
    sf::Vector2f position;
    m_TileGrid.x = 0.0;
    m_TileGrid.y = 0.0;
    float xPos = 0.f, yPos = 0.f;
    for (int x = 0; x < 48; x++)
    {
        yPos = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < 27; y++)
        {
            m_TileGrid.x = x * 40.f; m_TileGrid.y = y * 40.f;
            //m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(xPos, yPos);
            if (y < 20)
            {
                m_TileSprite[x][y].setTexture(m_Water05);
            }
            else 
            {
                m_TileSprite[x][y].setTexture(m_Cobble01);
            }
            m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(xPos, yPos);
            yPos += 40;
        }
        xPos += 40;
    }
}

Sprite Tim::getTileSprite(int x, int y)
{
    return m_TileSprite[x][y];
}
void Tim::setTileSpritePos(int x, int y)
{
    m_TileGrid.x = x*40.f;
    m_TileGrid.y = y*40.f;
    m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(m_TileGrid);
    //m_TileSprite[x][y].sf::Transformable.m_position.x = m_TileGrid.x;
    //m_TileSprite[x][y].sf::Transformable.m_position.y = m_TileGrid.y;
    //  setPosition(m_TileGrid);
}

//Engine.h
//Adopted and adapted from Engine.h from http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-a-simple-game-engine-in-c-plus-plus/
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Tim.h";

using namespace sf;

class Engine
{
private:
    RenderWindow m_Window;
    Tim m_Tim;
    void draw();
    void firstDraw();

public:
    Engine();
    void start();

};

//Engine.cpp  -variant
//Adopted and adapted from Engine.cpp from http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-a-simple-game-engine-in-c-plus-plus/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Engine.h"

Engine::Engine()
{
    Vector2f resolution;
    resolution.x = VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    resolution.y = VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;

    m_Window.create(VideoMode(resolution.x, resolution.y),
        "Simple Game Engine",
        Style::Fullscreen);



}

void Engine::start()
{
    firstDraw();
    while (m_Window.isOpen())
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            m_Window.close();
        }
    }
}

//Draw.ccp
//Adopted and adapted from Draw.cpp from http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-a-simple-game-engine-in-c-plus-plus/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Engine.h"

void Engine::firstDraw()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 48; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 27; y++)
        {
            m_Tim.setTileSpritePos(x, y);
        }
    }

    draw();
}
void Engine::draw()
{
    m_Window.clear(Color::White);

    for (int x = 0; x < 48; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 27; y++)
        {
            if (y>8)
            {
                m_Window.draw(m_Tim.getTileSprite(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
    m_Window.display();
}

//Main.cpp
//Adopted and adapted from Main.cpp from http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-a-simple-game-engine-in-c-plus-plus/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Engine.h"

int main()
{
    Engine engine;

    engine.start();

    return 0;
}
```

The "water" at the top, above the white - should actually be "cobble" and below where the cobble line at the bottom is.

Comment: On line 42 you define ypos as a 16-bit variable.

Comment: @stark: That can hold 65536 distinct values (0 to 65535 or -32768 to +32767) so it doesn't explain wrapping at 800.

Comment: @BenVoigt  But on line 43 OP multiplies by 40.

Comment: I don't see any source code where you get your line numbers, but my understanding of the question is that a number `y` in the range 0...26 is getting multiplied by 40 to form `yPos`.

Comment: @stark Line 42 and 43 of what? Is there something missing on my side? I don't see any exposed code of OP.

Comment: Btw. if it works with `m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(0, 920);` but not with `m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(xPos, yPos);` where `xPos = x*40; yPos = y*40;`... this smells like Undefined Behavior. Have you checked the values of `x`, `y`, `xPos`, and `yPos` in debugger just before call of `setPosition()`?

Comment: @Scheff Yes. All the values of the variables match the desired values.  I checked that before asking the question hoping that the values would give me a clue.

It's almost like the window was created using resolution.y =800, but then scaled to fit 1080.  But `resolution.y = VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;` is returning 1080.

Comment: @BenVoigt Correct.  0<=y<27 and 0<=x<48 for yPos in the set of (0,40,80,...,800,840,880,920,960,1000,1040) and xPos in the set of (0,40,80,...1800,1840,1880).

Comment: @stark I also do not know where you get lines 42 and 43.

Comment: The line `yPos * 40.0;` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @interjay that was a transfer typo

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We can't guess based on incomplete code snippets that you haven't tested.

Comment: There's just not enough of your code here to solve your problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, hoped the snippets would be enough because an executable variant would be bulky.  Added the variant

Comment: You seem to have some redundancies here -- `m_TileGrid.x` ought to always be the same as `xPos`.  And `setTileSpritePos` doesn't seem to be called but it would also recalculate `m_TileGrid.x` and call `m_TileSprite[x][y].setPosition(m_TileGrid);` just like the for loop is already doing.  Oh now I see, that function *is* called during `firstDraw`.  Are all the calculations failing or do they disagree?  If you read back the position after you set it, do you get the original value or has it wrapped?

Comment: @BenVoigt It's wrapping even after setting.  I have multiple methods in there because I thought that some type conversion issues may have been a factor.  I gave some of it in commented form to show other methods I've tried and setting the variables even I didn't use them on this iteration didn't seem to be a problem.